# Printing an acronym list with only <acronym> and <full name> using the acronym package

Tags: acronyms

I am using the acronym package which defines the acronyms using the command \acro which is called with the arguments: \acro{acronym}[short name]{full name}. It is defined in the acronym environment as:

```
\newenvironment{acronym}{%
\begin{description}
\providecommand*{\acro}[1]{\AC@dblargafter{##1}\AC@acro}%
}{%
\end{description}%
}
\newcommand\AC@acro{}
\def\AC@acro#1[#2]#3{%
\acrodef{#1}[{#2}]{#3}%
\item[{#2}] #3%
}
```

Next is an example of the acronym list:

```
\acro{AC}[alternating current]{Alternating Current}
```

After compiling, the list is:

**alternating current** Alternating Current

Instead of:

**AC** Alternating Current

How to modify this environnement to get the {acronym} instead of the [short name] in the acronym list, without deleting the [short name] since I need the lowercased form in the text by calling it with the command \acs.
Any help would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use `\newacronym{AC}{AC}{Alternating Current}`

[image: a]

Try this code. (`pdflatex` + `makeglossaries` + `pdflatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{AC}{AC}{Alternating Current}

\begin{document}
 
    The long  \acrlong{AC}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{AC}.     
    
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    
\end{document}
```